# What type of cleat is this? Should I save it or get new cleats?

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes, cleat

Can someone tell me what kind of cleat this is? circa 1993. I believe I got it  Someone told me that I can just get new shoes (the shoes are completely shot) and reuse the cleat.  Is that a good idea or should I get new cleats?  I think it's the shoes that are really expensive.  I am a very casual rider (go with kids) but I'm now used to the clip in style.

[image]

Here's a photo of the actual pedal.  Naturally, when I get new shoes (and cleats?) I want to make sure they fit pedal.
[image]

Comment: (comment rather than answer as mainly dealing with product rec. bit). You can get shoes that are cleat-compatible but OK when you get off the bike and neither look not sound superficially like bike shoes. I went for "specialised cadet" but there are plenty of designs widely available.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bog-standard "mountain" SPD cleat.  (Good luck getting the screws out!!)

Comment: A new pair of SPD type shoes will most likely come with at least one set of cleats, so if you're buying new shoes don't worry about saving these cleats

Comment: @Adam many shoes are compatible with more than one type of cleat. You're more likely to get cleats with the pedals.

Comment: @ChrisH we'll have to agree to disagree there. I've always received cleats when purchasing SPD style shoes.

Comment: I’ve never received cleats when buying shoes (I also don’t know of anybody who did). There are lots of other manufacturers out there.

Comment: @Adam Really?  Even Shimano mtn bike shoes do not ship with SPD cleats.

Comment: @Frisbee yes really. I've mainly bought Specialized MTB shoes, and never have bought cleats separately. I don't know if location makes a dif but I'm in Aus. In any case, Dave if you buy new shoes, make sure they're SPD compatible, if they don't come with cleats, buy some SPD cleats, give those pedals a clean up and adjust the tension, and you're back in business.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a Shimano SPD cleat. There are a few different models, but they are all cross compatible. You can reuse the old ones if you can unscrew it, but new pair should be under 20€, too.

EDIT: Looks like this is an old Shimano cleat, like this one: http://www.fixedgeargallery.com/reviews/dzr/ovis/10.jpg. Modern ones and most copies have a sharp angled "shoulder" on the middle section.

Comment: The cleat in the pic looks so worn I wouldn't reuse it though.

Comment: You would also likely struggle to get it out without drilling the bolts. I'd say just get new ones.

Comment: Just in case it's unclear, the odds of being able to unscrew those cleats are only slightly better than the odds of winning the lottery.

Comment: Drilling them would probably not do you lot of good as then you would have to find screws and those are very specific.  Hit them with penetrating oil and let them sit a day and give removing a try.  If they worked on the old shoes they will work the same on the new shoes.   Grease the threads before putting them in the new shoes.

Comment: Thanks OJS.  When you say they are "all cross compatible", does that mean if I get an SPD cleat it will work with my existing pedals? I've posted a picture of my original pedal under my main post.  Unfortunately, I can't see any make or model # on it. Obviously, if I go the route of getting new cleats, they have to work with existing pedal.

Comment: Yes, all SPD pedals are compatible with all SPD cleats. The pedal looks like it might not be a genuine Shimano but one of the several knockoffs, which are generally compatible with Shimano and each others. I don't see why someone would make similar pedal that wasn't actually compatible.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it is an old Shimano cleat, much like this one: http://www.fixedgeargallery.com/reviews/dzr/ovis/10.jpg. The newer ones have sharp "shoulder" which made me suspect these are not originals.

Answer (score 3):

You should accept the answer from OJS but this is too much for a comment.

SPD is the format of the attachment from Shimano.  They have a patent on SPD - if it includes the shape of the cleat I don't know.  Even if so a patent does not stop copies.

The shoe just has a hole pattern that will accept a number of cleats.

As much as stuff changes in bicycles the [SPD](http://www.shimano-lifestylegear.com/us/pd/technologies/spd_25years.php) has been around for a while.

As beat up as that pedal is I think I would try the existing cleats first. Like I said in a comment try a day of penetrating oil.  You could even cut the cleat out of the shoes and soak the whole thing.  Not sure if that is worth saving like $13.  If you replace the pedals they will come with cleats.  Those cleats are not in terrible shape (well compared to the pedal).

And that looks like an original Shimano to me.  That looks like the original M737.